# How to set search box to the center?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How to set a Search Box/Text Field to the center of tool bar?

Here is the code I am using...

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    width   : 500,
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Button1'
        },
        '->',
        {
            xtype    : 'textfield',
            name     : 'field1',
            emptyText: 'Enter search term'
        },
        '-',
        {
            text: 'Button2'
        }
    ]
});
```

Note : I am using Extjs 4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add  `'->'` or `{ xtype: 'tbfill' }` also after textfield definition:

```js
items: [
    {
        text: 'Button1'
    },
    '->',
    {
        xtype    : 'textfield',
        name     : 'field1',
        emptyText: 'Enter search term'
    },
    '->',
    '-',
    {
        text: 'Button2'
    }
]
```